# TypeScript: passing an empty array to a generic method

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Given I have this code:

```js
const myGenericMethod = <T extends MyType1 | MyType2>(myList: T[]): T[] => {
  return myList; // simplified, my real method would return a shuffled list
};

type MyType1 = { name: 'Type1' };
type MyType2 = { name: 'Type2' };

const myList: MyType1[] | MyType2[] = [];
myGenericMethod(myList); // error!
```

the last line will lead to a type error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'MyType1[] | MyType2[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyType1[]'.
   Type 'MyType2[]' is not assignable to type 'MyType1[]'.
     Type 'MyType2' is not assignable to type 'MyType1'.
       Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
         Type '"Type2"' is not assignable to type '"Type1"'.
```

When I change the the `myList` creation to

```js
const myList: MyType1[] | MyType2[] = [{ name: 'Type1' }];
```

it will work though.

My TypeScript version is `4.9.4`. How can I properly support empty lists?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? Why do you need 2 types where the name is different? Aren't you mixing up Type definition with objects?

Comment: @BrunoMarotta: It's just a simplified example. I need a generic method which shuffles elements in an array and returns the shuffled array, and I want to use generics to tell that the returned array has the same element type as before. And the array I'm passing could just be `[]` (coming from `const toShuffle = ... || []`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid, the answer is that my method declaration leads to a wrong union type:

```js
const myGenericMethod = (myList: (MyType1 | MyType2)[]): (MyType1 | MyType2)[]
```

while I meant

```js
const myGenericMethod = (myList: MyType1[] | MyType2[]): MyType1[] | MyType2[]
```

So I changed my method to

```
const myGenericMethod = <T extends any[]>(myList: T): T => {
  return myList;
};
```

There was nothing wrong with the empty array!